# Inject a dependency inside an object

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework-2.0

I'm new to the Play framework and scala and I'm trying to inject a dependency inside a companion object.

I have a simple case class, like:

```
case class Bar(foo: Int) {}
```

With a companion object like:

```
object Bar {
  val myDependency =
  if (isTest) {
    // Mock
  }
  else
  {
    // Actual implementation
  }

  val form = Form(mapping(
    "foo" -> number(0, 100).verifying(foo => myDependency.validate(foo)), 
  )(Bar.apply)(Bar.unapply))
}
```

This works fine, but it's not really a clean way to do it. I'd like to be able to inject the dependency at build time so that I can inject different mock objects when testing and different real implementations in development and production.

What's the best way to achieve this?

Any help really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I think what you need is a so-called "cake pattern". There was a blog post by Daniel Spiewak, but I can't seem to find it. But this ( http://www.warski.org/blog/2011/04/di-in-scala-cake-pattern-pros-cons/ ) should be good as a reference.

Comment: This is the [original post](http://jonasboner.com/2008/10/06/real-world-scala-dependency-injection-di/) from Jonas Boner

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of the *Cake*, we can try to change your example to

```
trait Validator {
    def validate(foo: Int): Boolean
}

trait TestValidation {
    val validator = new Validator {
        def validate(foo: Int): Boolean = ...   
    }
}

trait ImplValidation {
    val validator = new Validator {
        def validate(foo: Int): Boolean = ...   
    }
}


trait BarBehavior {
    def validator: Validator

    val form = Form(mapping(...))(Bar.apply)(Bar.unapply)
}

//use this in your tests
object TestBar extends BarBehavior with TestValidation

//use this in production
object ImplBar extends BarBehavior with ImplValidation
```

You should additionally try and test if this example fits well within the Play Framework, too

Comment: Thanks, @pagoda_5b. I get an error in the object Bar "Only classes can have declared but undefined members"

Comment: Also "Unspecified value parameters: foo: Int" where I write 
`object ImplBar extends Bar with ImplValidation` (where `foo: Int` is the only attribute of Bar)

Comment: I updated the code to correctly use a trait for the base Bar Behavior, but I guess this doesn't fit well with your need to define a companion object to Bar... I'll elaborate more